# AVCapture doesn't fill whole view

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-autolayout

I'm trying to display live camera video in a view, but when I run the following code, it doesn't fill up the whole screen. It only fills up 3.5 inch screen size (running on 5.5 inch screen). I have set up the `autolayout` of the view to 0 on each side.

```
    session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    [session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto];
    AVCaptureDevice *inputDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    NSError *error;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *deviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:inputDevice error:&error];
    if ([session canAddInput:deviceInput]) {
        [session addInput:deviceInput];
    }
    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
    [previewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
    CALayer *rootLayer = [[self view] layer];
    [rootLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    CGRect frame = frameForCapture.frame;
    [previewLayer setFrame:frame];
    [rootLayer insertSublayer:previewLayer atIndex:0];
    stillImage = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
    [stillImage setOutputSettings:outputSettings];
    [session addOutput:stillImage];
    [session startRunning];
```

When I set the view controller's size from 3.5-inch to 5.5-inch and run, it fills up the screen though. The `autolayout` is working when size changes, but not when It runs.

Comment: Your code uses a `frameForCapture` but doesn't show where it comes from.

Comment: try to set the frame for the previewLayer in viewDidAppear rather than in viewDidLoad. Hope, it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Layers don't adhere to autoresizing/auto layout the same way that views do, you'll need to manually set the layer's frame on resize. A nice way to do this is to introduce a view subclass that contains the preview layer and sets its frame to the view's bounds in `-layoutSubviews`